# Set Ship Bundle Items to default to "Separately"

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

Is there any way I can set the setting for bundle items "Ship Bundle Items" to "Separately" by default when new bundle products are created? Currently, it automatically sets this option to `Together`.

In `eav_attribute` table, I found the `shipmnet_type` and set default value to 1, but it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and Magento 2 is out now, so I will answer this for Magento 2.

If you change the "default_value" column in the eav_attribute table for the shipment_type attribute, the "Ship Bundle Items" dropdown will default to "Separately" when creating a new bundle product.